# Sonar successful authentication without password

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I'm working on LDAP authentication support for Sonar. Users can authenticate using Blank password (No password) Or Correct password. If a wrong password entered, authentication fails. 
Sonar should not allow any login with a blank password even when this authentication depends on an external system like LDAP, could you help me to find a solution for this problem

Stacktrace in sonar.log:

```
`2015.04.27 18:39:19 DEBUG o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider  User admin not found
 2015.04.27 18:39:19 DEBUG User admin not found
 2015.04.27 18:39:19 DEBUG o.s.p.l.LdapUsersProvider  Requesting details for user admin
 2015.04.27 18:39:19 DEBUG o.s.p.l.LdapSearch  Search:  LdapSearch{baseDn=DC=mycompany,DC=mycompany,DC=com, scope=subtree, request=(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=gpfrcip-java,OU=IDC,OU=DSI,OU=DDA - France,OU=Access groups,OU=Groups,OU=Resources,DC=mycompany,DC=mycompany,DC=com)(SAMAccountName={0})), parameters=[admin], attributes=[mail, cn]}
 2015.04.27 18:39:19 DEBUG o.s.p.l.LdapContextFactory  Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url= myURL, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, java.naming.security.principal=, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.referral=follow}
 2015.04.27 18:39:19 DEBUG Requesting details for user admin
 2015.04.27 18:39:19 DEBUG Search: LdapSearch{baseDn=DC=mycompany,DC=mycompany,DC=com, scope=subtree, request=(&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=gpfrcip-java,OU=IDC,OU=DSI,OU=DDA - France,OU=Access groups,OU=Groups,OU=Resources,DC=mycompany,DC=mycompany,DC=com)(SAMAccountName={0})), parameters=[admin], attributes=[mail, cn]}
 2015.04.27 18:39:19 DEBUG Initializing LDAP context {java.naming.provider.url= myURL, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory, java.naming.security.principal=, com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool=true, java.naming.security.authentication=simple, java.naming.referral=follow}
```

`

LDAP Configuration for sonar-ldap-plugin-1.2 :

```
sonar.security.realm: LDAP
sonar.authenticator.createUsers: false
ldap.url: myURL
ldap.user.baseDn: DC=mycompany,DC=mycompany,DC=com
ldap.bindDn:
ldap.bindPassword:
ldap.user.request: (&(objectClass=user)(memberof=CN=gpfrcip-  java,OU=IDC,OU=DSI,OU=DDA - France,OU=Access groups,OU=Groups,OU=Resources,DC=mycompany,DC=mycompany,DC=com)(SAMAccountName={0}))
```

`

Any feedback will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your feedbacks.

Regards
Youssef ALAMI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem, i changed the version of the plugin LDAP to sonar-ldap-plugin-1.4 and the authentication was worked correctly.